# Посчитать кол-во значений в массиве по условиям

Tags: php

У меня есть большой массив данных из чисел

```
array(5,5,10,20,30,40,50,64,7,10);
```

Как мне вывести из него кол-во значений от и до, как :

От 0 - 10

От 11 - 20

...

От 91-100

У меня получилось так, но это кажется не правильно

```
$array = array(5,5,10,20,30,40,50,64,7,10);

function Counter($array, $from, $to) {
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($array as $number) {
        if($number <= $to && $number >= $from) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}

echo "<p>0 - 10:" . Counter($array, 0, 10). "</p>";
echo "<p>11 - 20:" . Counter($array, 11, 20). "</p>";
echo "<p>21 - 30:" . Counter($array, 21, 30). "</p>";
```

Comment: Ну ты хоть как-то попытался сам делать?

Comment: Пытался с помощью циклов, но это выглядит глупо :/

Comment: Где там глупо-то? просто цикл с 1 условием. Ты хотя бы отсортировал массив сначала?

Comment: @Ипатьев зачем его сортировать, если это за один проход считается?

Comment: По отсортированному логика будет на порядок проще. А он и так в штанинах путается.

Comment: Обновил вопрос как сделал я

Comment: Нормальное решение, только вывод тоже в цикл надо поместить, а не от руки писать

Comment: Только почему $count=1? так у тебя насчитает 1 лишний элемент

Comment: ой точно, должен быть 0

Comment: @Ипатьев я может тупой, но вообще не вижу, как тут сортировка может повлиять на алгоритм подсчета :) по моему это из области, отсортировать массив, чтобы найти максимум/минимум.

Answer (score 1):

Для данных диапазонов ([ideone](https://ideone.com/EuUQbS)):

```
$array = array(5,5,10,20,30,40,50,64,7,10);
$a = array_fill(0, 10, 0);
foreach ($array as $number) 
  $a[(int)($number/10)]++;
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$numbers    = [105, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 64, 7, 10, 99, 65, 44, 23, 150, 90, 12, 22, 16, 77, 74, 83, 90];
$conditions = [
    [0, 10],
    [11, 20],
    [21, 30],
    [30, 100]
];

foreach ($conditions as $cond) {
    foreach ($numbers as $num) {
        if ($num >= $cond[0] && $num <= $cond[1]) $countByCond["From $cond[0] to $cond[1]"]++;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r ($countByCond);
```

---

```
Array
(
    [From 0 to 10] => 4
    [From 11 to 20] => 3
    [From 21 to 30] => 3
    [From 30 to 100] => 12
)
```